# Can any one elaborate Shopify default _st js object?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

When I execute `console.log(__st);`
in any Shopify site, it returns JSON

```
{
  "a": 22971355,
  "offset": -14400,
  "reqid": "aa1c5fad-1b95-43c2-aa29-c6d053e5c6d0",
  "pageurl": "demo-new-store-1.myshopify.com/",
  "t": "prospect",
  "u": "e50223bc3803",
  "cid": 213975957513,
  "p": "home"
}
```

What the meaning of all element and how used(help) it  I know some of them 
except a, t, u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__st` It looks like this is an internal object for Shopify internal tools/app. It has internal data about the page/user etc.

I do not think this object is intended to be used by anyone outside of Shopify dev team.